# Connecting to an azure Service Fabric App

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to debug why my Service Cluster App is stuck during the upgrade session.
I've looked up how to do it with powershell and I found the command:

`Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade fabric:/My.Fabric.App.Name`

This command throws the error:

> Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade : Cluster connection instance is null

So naturally, I tried connecting to the cluster with:

`Connect-ServiceFabricCluster myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000`

But I got:

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
>   WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
>   False
>   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : One or more errors occurred.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-ServiceFabricCluster myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], AggregateException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

Service fabric is annoying.. Please help? :\

**UPDATE**

It's probably because my fabric is secured and I have a client cert that I have to use to connect.

I tried the following config for the command:

```
$connectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = 'myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000';  X509Credential = $True;  StoreLocation = 'CurrentUser';  StoreName = "MY";  ServerCommonName = "myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com";  FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  FindValue = "DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF"; SkipChecks = $True  }
```

But `Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade` still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success!

With the following arguments:

```
$connectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = 'myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19000';  
                   X509Credential = $True;  
                   StoreLocation = "CurrentUser";  
                   StoreName = "My";  
                   ServerCommonName = "myfabric.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com";  
                   FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  
                   FindValue = "81EBFC23D456130C0CA99952484240EA2385F0C3"; 
                   ServerCertThumbprint = "DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF" }

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @connectArgs
```

Comment: it is also simpler  ~ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "win243ypm67426.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000" -SkipChecks $True